# How to bind an empty array to the props in Vue.js3?

Tags: arrays, typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>   
  interface Props {
    bigArray: string[];
  }
        
  ***const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    bigArray:[],
  }*** <---- Here is the error, setting props
        
  const bigArray = ref(props.BigArray);
</script>
```

#### ITsInterface.ts

```js
BigArray?: string[] | null;
```

Looking for the proper way to set up an empty array as a prop in this scenario:

- Vue.js3
- composition API
- TypeScript
- setup in script tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import { withDefaults, defineProps} from "vue";

interface Props {
    bigArray?: string[]
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    bigArray: () => []
})

console.log(props.bigArray);
```

You just needed to add the `() =>` arrow-function for it to work.

This is shown [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features) in the vue documentation.

And if you want to make the prop optional (as it should be with a default value) use `?` after the variable-name. This will ensure there are no unnecessary warnings in the console.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to have a prop with multiple products but when there are no products i want a default array. Not sure why but adding '() => [],' instead of '[]' fixed the issue.

type PropTypes = {
    products: Product[],
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<PropTypes>(), {
  products: () => [],
});

Comment: @Whitespacecode so my solution works? - if so feel free to upvote the answer, or do you need any further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the vue documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation).

You could do it like that:

```
const props = defineProps({
  bigArray: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
  }
});
```

This defines a prop with the name `bigArray` and sets the default to an empty array.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but the prop has been set as a type: string previous in the interface

Comment: @randomfool yeah i know - i thought you just need one option. Didn't know you want/need the interface - will take a further look at this later